# Read multiple files and change fields

Tags: python, bash, awk

I have 2 files like these:

file1

> 1 2   3   .   .   .
>
> **1   -2**    4   .   .   .
>
> 1 2   5   .   .   .
>
> . .   .   .   .   .
>
> .   .   .   .   .

file 2

> 1 0.33    3   .   .   .
>
> 2 0.14    4   .   .   .
>
> 3 2.155   5   .   .   .
>
> . .   .   .   .   .
>
> . .   .   .   .   .

I need to check line by line the condition ($1==1 && $2==-2) in file1 and modify the corresponding line in file2, with $3=-2

I am trying with:

```
awk -F '\t' '{ BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" } if ($1==1 && ($2==-2) {getline < "file2" ; $3=8; print $0} else {getline < "file2" ; print $0}  }' file1
```

So that the output file should be:

> 1 0.33    3   .   .   .
>
> 2 0.14    **8**   .   .   .
>
> 3 2.155   5   .   .   .
>
> . .   .   .   .   .
>
> . .   .   .   .   .

but it seems like some character or space is modified.
Maybe with Python it is simpler to tackle this problem?
Any suggestion?

Comment: What about a solution with python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you asked about python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

with open('f1') as  fd:
    f1 = [map(int,i.strip().split()) for i in fd]
with open('f2') as  fd:
    f2 = [map(float,i.strip().split()) for i in fd]

for n, f in enumerate(f2):
    if f1[n][0] == 1 and f1[n][1] == -2:
        print f[0], f[1], 8
    else:
        print f
```

Comment: Only `if (...) f[2]=8` Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `-F` since you're setting `FS` and `OFS` inside your `BEGIN` block.

You have some curly braces and parentheses out of place.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t" } {if ($1 == 1 && $2 == -2) {getline < "file2"; $3 = 8} else {getline < "file2"}; print  }' file1
1   0.33    3
2   0.14    8
3   2.155   5
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the output field separator in `awk` as well:

```
awk -F '\t' -v OFS='\t' ' { if ... }' file1
```

FYI, the `paste` and `cut` commands can simplify the `awk` script:

```
cut -f1,2 file1 | paste - file2 | \
awk -F '\t' -v OFS '\t' '$1==1 && $2==-2 {$5=8}; {print}' | \
cut -f3-
```

You take just the first two fields from each line of file1, use `paste` to add them to the beginning of the corresponding line in file2, then modify field *5* (corresponding to field 3 in file2) if appropriate and output the entire line, and finally strip out the fields from file1.

Comment: The solution with the combination of cut, past and awk is very brilliant! It seems to work at first sight. Anyway, once I use the output file as an input file for a python script (in which I need to create a an array with a particular field and a matrix with almost the rest of the fields), it returns "arr = N.array(data, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.". Maybe, there are some problems with char and float. Thus, I suppose it is better to translate this code directly in python... Is there a fast solution for this problem? Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I did with `bash` & `sed`, I don't know why (but there's the `bash` tag on the question, so it's kinda on topic):

```
$ cat /tmp/1
1   2   3   .   .   .
1   -2  4   .   .   .
1   -2  5   .   .   .
.   .   .   .   .   .
.   .   .   .   .
```

(tab-separated)

```
$ cat /tmp/2
1   0.33    3   .   .   .
2   0.14    4   .   .   .
3   2.155   5   .   .   .
.   .   .   .   .   .
.   .   .   .   .   .

$ lines=`grep -n "^1      -2      " /tmp/1 | sed 's/:.*//'`
$ for l in $lines; do sed -ri "${l}s/^(\S*)\t(\S*)\t\S*/\1\t\2\t8/" /tmp/2; done
$ cat /tmp/2
1   0.33    3   .   .   .
2   0.14    8   .   .   .
3   2.155   8   .   .   .
.   .   .   .   .   .
.   .   .   .   .   .
```

*This is probably awful scripting, I've never been good at bash, but I'll justify the wasted time by posting it.*